# how to copy part of data base to android if ofline

Tags: android, database, firebase

I'm learning android and now i'm in data Base
I want database Has quick response with the server 
and in the same time it is a part of data Base exists on Mobile
in the case of non-contact to internet

i like Fire base , but i do't no How the database will be on the android in the case of non-contact to internet ??

Comment: The Firebase SDK for Android support offline operation. It'll persist the data to device storage. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html I highly recommend reading that entire page and the rest of the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android the supported database is SQLite, however I found your statements kind of weird. You have a local database and a database in the server (that can be any on Market, DB2, Oracle, MySql, ETC). Don't mix the both of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. 
Example for i mean .. Chat be registered on the server but if you offline you can also reed the chat .. How does it happen if i create the data base on Fire base ?